# Is it safe to use mutable let bindings inside task CEs or async CEs?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task, computation-expression

When you think you know, you don't know, is what went through my head earlier today. While going over someone's code I noticed something similar to:

```ml
task {
    let mutable pleaseContinue = true
    let mutable state = MyState.Running
    while pleaseContine do
        match x with
        | Ok -> 
             // do something
             do! runSomeTasks()
             state <- MyState.Running
             pleaseContinue <- true
        | Error err ->
             do! Log.Fatal err "Something bad"
             state <- MyState.Crashed
             pleaseContinue <- false
        | ... // originally many other states
    return 
}
```

Basically, whenever I see `mutable` in someone else's code I tend to want to get rid of it. But short of that, I found myself wondering whether the mutable variables inside `task` and the like are properly part of the closure and are safe to read/update/write, as long as they aren't defined outside the `task` CE builder.

Is this a correct and safe assumption?

This is in F# 6.0, and using `Microsoft.FSharp.Control.TaskBuilder` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

This looks fine to me.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions.

The builder implements the body of the while loop as a recursive function. It can modify `state` and `pleaseContinue` since the variables are in scope.

I'm just not clear where the `x` that you refer to is declared or mutated - presumably as part of the omitted code before the `return` statement. In any case, if it is in scope, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. This confirms what I thought, but I needed confirmation. I left `x` out (and 200 other lines of code), but it wasn't an external mutable var, just an normal immutable let-binding.

Comment: Hmm, come to think of it: `while` becomes a `rec` function, but the vars are declared outside of it. If it is a `rec` function, it can only be run by one thread. But if it isn't and the `while` is parallelized (it's a task CE), that sounds like a potential problem still... Any thoughts?